# What do you call it when you add zeros between the elements of a vector?

Tags: terminology

What do you call it when you add zeros between the elements of a vector?

let's say you have `x =[1 2 3 4]`

and `x_2 = [0 1 0 2 0 3 0 4]`

what do you call this process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the context of filter banks, simply [upsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsampling) (without filtering, or with the trivial all-pass filter, as Wikipedia relates it to interpolation), denoted by an up-arrow, as illustrated below fro a 2-fold or order-2 upsampling:

[image]

This is described in [Filter banks: Decimation, Interpolation, and Modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_bank#Decimation.2C_Interpolation.2C_and_Modulation), and the  interpolation filter associated with upsampling is called synthesis filter.

As noted by @Jason R, one also finds "expansion". Expansion is also found as [a streching for continuous signals](http://www.dspguide.com/ch10/4.htm), while compression is the effect in the dual Fourier domain. Sometimes, one can find "zero-insertion" or "zero-stuffing".

Actually in image processing some use "upsampling" as a proxy for pixel increase with filtering.

Comment: is it still called up sampling if you intend to use it as part of hermitian symmetry?

Comment: @HappyBee One can upsample a complex signal. However, I am not sure I understand how you want to use it in Hermitian symmetry

Comment: let's say I have `x = [m1 m2 m3 m4]` I want to generate a signal that would have a hermitian symmetry out of `x` (in an OFDM system) i.e I would start by doing `s =[0 m1 0 m2 0 m3 0 m4]` then `s_2 = [0 m1 0 m2 0 m3 0 m4 0 m4* 0 m3* 0 m2* 0 m1*]` I would say now that `s_2` has hermitian symmetry @Laurent

Comment: I've also seen this operation described in DSP texts as *expansion* in contrast to *interpolation* where you would actually filter the result.

Comment: @Jason R indeed, thank you, I have given a more precise context.

Comment: @HappyBee I would that an upsampling of the Hermitian folded signal too